# PyQt getsavefilename shows error "Python has stopped working" when canceling save

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I have a problem with [pyqt5](/questions/tagged/pyqt5) `getsavefilename` when saving a file from a textedit.

When I am saving a file it is working there is no problem but when I want to close the save dialog without saving it is giving me error:

> python has stopped working

I'am using python 3.6

**Code**

```
def fileSave(self):
    filename = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save A File', '/home')

    with open(filename[0], 'w') as f:
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        f.write(text)
        f.close()
```

**Error screenshot**
  [image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

When you cancel the `QFileDialog` it returns as an empty text, and when you want to open a file with a non-existent name, it generates that error. Also if you are using `with` to open the file it is not necessary to close the file, just quit the`with` it will be closed automatically

```
def fileSave(self):
    filename, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save A File', '/home')

    if filename != "":
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
            f.write(text)
```

**Update:**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.button = QPushButton("Print")
        lay.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.filePrintPdf)

    def filePrintPdf(self): 
        fn, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Export PDF", None, "PDF files (.pdf);;All Files ()") 
        if fn != "": 
            if QFileInfo(fn).suffix() == "": fn += '.pdf' 
        printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution) 
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat) 
        printer.setOutputFileName(fn) 
        self.textEdit.document().print_(printer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you now it is working, can u tell me that how i can print a text from textedit as a pdf file in pyqt5

Comment: when i run this code it is giving me error                                                     def filePrintPdf(self):
        fn, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Export PDF", None,
                                            "PDF files (*.pdf);;All Files (*)")

        if fn:
            if QFileInfo(fn).suffix().isEmpty():
                fn += '.pdf'

            printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
            printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
            printer.setOutputFileName(fn)
            self.textEdit.document().print_(printer)

Comment: @Parwiz  As I told you, the best way to thank is to mark my answer as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour]